# xmlHttp return null every time

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have java script ajax codes and those are:

```
var xmlHttp = new GetXmlHttpObject();

function answer()
{

if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        alert("response is given");
        alert(xmlHttp.responseXML);
        document.getElementById("bl").innerHTML =xmlHttp.responseText;
        randNum();
    }
else{
        document.getElementById("bl").innerHTML='<img src="so/loading.gif">';
    }
}

function sendCode()
{
var param="";
var sender_name = document.getElementById("sender_name").value;
var sender_emaile = document.getElementById("sender_emaile").value;
var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
var security_code=document.feedback.security_code.value;
var security_code_id=document.feedback.security_code_id.value;
var responsibility = 123;

if(sender_name=="" || sender_emaile=="" || subject=="" || message=="" || security_code=="")
{ 

}else{
    param += "sender_name="+sender_name+"&sender_emaile="+sender_emaile+"&subject="+subject+"&message="+message+"&security_code="+security_code+"&responsibility="+responsibility+"&security_code_id="+security_code_id;
    xmlHttp.open("POST","http://www.acn.org/modules.php?name=Feedback&action=response",true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=answer;
    xmlHttp.send(param);
    }
}
```

but my problem is xmlHttp.responseXML return Null , but i could see the http response in the Wiresahrk(packet sniffer). I even get response when i manually enter URL .

How should I debug it?

**Edited**:

The Wireshark packet contain a lot of my server/client properties but I can say in the **Hypertext Transfer Protocol** contain two parts and a section after it ,

first part is

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n

which contain request header and second part is

> HTTP chunked response

which say content encoded entity body (gzip)

next and last section is:

> Line-Base text data: text/html

which contain response that I wanted , but it don't shows by  xmlHttp.responseXML or xmlHttp.responseText .

```
<div> some text </div>
```

Comment: The problem could be that you are using a global `xmlhttp` object.

Comment: Unbelievable people still use this way of ajax programming. I haven't seen this already for at least a couple of years... What's wrong with jQuery? JSON?

Comment: This is not me , This is PHPNuke :) , i know Jquery offers a agile methods.

Comment: @Golix I'll remember never to use that then hahaha I don't think xml should ever be used with javascript anymore, it's only useful with webservices

Comment: @bicycle [There's nothing wrong with jQuery, but that doesn't mean you can't use pure _JavaScript_](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122191/what-benefits-are-there-to-native-javascript-development). I'm not saying this is the prettiest by any means, but knowing how to do it without a library is no bad thing.

Comment: @PaulS. Unless you have want your users to have a fast web experience without having to download all that code. jQuery is normally already cached within the browser. You shouldn't bother your user with javascript enthusiasm i think....

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are using a global `xmlhttp` object.

Try

```
function answer(xmlHttp)
{

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        alert("response is given");
        alert(xmlHttp.responseXML);
        document.getElementById("bl").innerHTML =xmlHttp.responseText;
        randNum();
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("bl").innerHTML='<img src="so/loading.gif">';
    }
}

function sendCode()
{
    var param="";
    var sender_name = document.getElementById("sender_name").value;
    var sender_emaile = document.getElementById("sender_emaile").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var security_code=document.feedback.security_code.value;
    var security_code_id=document.feedback.security_code_id.value;
    var responsibility = 123;

    if(sender_name=="" || sender_emaile=="" || subject=="" || message=="" || security_code=="")
    { 

    }else{
        var xmlHttp = new GetXmlHttpObject();

        param += "sender_name="+sender_name+"&sender_emaile="+sender_emaile+"&subject="+subject+"&message="+message+"&security_code="+security_code+"&responsibility="+responsibility+"&security_code_id="+security_code_id;
        xmlHttp.open("POST","http://www.acn.org/modules.php?name=Feedback&action=response",true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            answer(xmlHttp);
        };
        xmlHttp.send(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Golix is `responseText` returning the value? also can you share the value found using `Wiresahrk`

Comment: responseText return nothing, i think it can't handle some kind of response.I will Add Wireshark packet.